# Probability that n people collectively occupy all 365 birthdays

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The problem is quite simple to formulate. If you have a large group of people (n > 365), and their birthdays are uniformly distributed over the year (365 days), what's the probability that every day of the year is someone's birthday?

I am thinking that the problem should be equivalent to finding the number of ways to place n unlabeled balls into k labeled boxes, such that all boxes are non-empty, but C((n-k)+k-1, (n-k))/C(n+k-1, n) (C(n,k) being the binomial coefficient) does not yield the correct answer.

Comment: I'm guessing 1-P(at least one day is no one's birthday) might be easier to calculate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Birthday Coverage is basically a [Coupon Collector's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem) problem.

You have $n$ people who drew birthdays with repetition, and wish to find the probability that all $365$ different days were drawn among all $n$ people.  ($n\geq 365$)

$$\mathsf P(T\leq n)= 365!\; \left\lbrace\begin{matrix}n\\365\end{matrix}\right\rbrace\; 365^{-n} $$

Where, the braces indicate a [Stirling number of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).   Also represented as $\mathrm S(n, 365)$.

Comment: I've tested empirically, and I made a solution using inclusion-exclusion, and you are correct, it is supposed to be 365!

Answer (score 3):

Just for sake of illustration I give some numerical results:

- for $1000$ people we get a propability of $1.7*10^{-10}$% to exhaust all birthdays
- for $1500$ people we get $0.2$%
- for $2000$ people we get $22$%
- for $2286$ people we get $50$%
- for $2500$ people we have $68$%
- for $3000$ people we have $91$%
- for $4000$ people we have $99$%

Answer (score 2):

Use the [inclusion-exclusion principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).  For a given set of $m$ days, the probability that nobody has a birthday on those days is $(1 - m/365)^n$.

EDIT: There are $365 \choose m$ such sets.  So the probability that there is at least one day with no birthdays is
$$\sum_{m=1}^{364} (-1)^{m-1}{365 \choose m} (1 - m/365)^n $$

Comment: I've manually done the calculations for 5 people and 3 birthdays, and gotten 150/243 as my probability. If I use inclusion exclusion, and name my boxes A, B and C, with |A| being the number of ways to fill the boxes making sure that A isn't empty, then |A|=|B|=|C|=3^4, |A∩B|=3^3, and |A∩B∩C| = 3^2, yielding 3*3^4-3*3^3+3^2 = 171, making the probability 171/243

Comment: Since you have to subtract your expression from $1$, I would have $\displaystyle \sum_{m=0}^{365} (-1)^{m}{365 \choose m} \left(1 - \dfrac{m}{365}\right)^n$ as the answer to the original question.