# What is the probability somebody's birthday is the day before mine?

Tags: probability, statistics

What is the probability that someone's birthday is the day before my birthday? For example, my birthday is Feb 28, what is the probability that my mom's birthday is Feb 27? Is it just $\frac1{365}$? That seems too simple to me but maybe I'm just complicating things unnecessarily.

Comment: Well, obviously the probability of her her birthday being Feb. 27 is 1/365 no matter what your birthday is.

Comment: What if your birthday is the 1st of March? Do the 29th and 28th of February both count then? So then there's the probability your birthday is the 1st of March, and the probability they're the 28th or 29th.

Comment: @fleablood The word "obviously" should be discouraged here. Although it was not your intention to be rude, it doesn't really help to say the answer is obvious in response to a question about that very thing.

Comment: @6005.  The question was about the probability of a birthday the day before and the OP gave an example of "if my birthday is 2/28" and her brthday is 2/27".  I was pointing out that the probability of her birthday being 2/27 is the same regardless of his birthday, hence the reason it isn't "too simplistic".

Comment: @fleablood I know what you meant! But what I'm pointing out is that the word "obviously" is almost guaranteed to be interpreted differently than you intended. If I ask, "what is X?" and you answer, "obviously, Y", I am likely to interpret that my question was stupid -- I should have known the answer myself.

Comment: More simply: what is obvious to you answering the question was obviously not obvious to the person asking. ;)

Comment: If this is for party trivia ("it's super uncommon for her birthday to be the day before mine!") you have to also consider that you'd say the same thing if you had the same birthday, or if hers was the day after yours.  Or if it was your father instead of mother. "What are the chances that parents have a child whose birthday is within 1 day of theirs" is still uncommon, but much less rare (about 1.6% with 1 child)

Comment: Depends. Which calendar? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_calendars ;)

Comment: it's also certainly not the case that a date of birth is equally likely to be any given day of the year, some months have consistently more births than others.

Answer (score 13):

*Assuming* a uniform distribution of birthdays throughout a 365-day year, *and* that "somebody" means "a fixed person chosen at random from the human population", $\frac1{365}$ is correct, since there is only one day that is immediately before a given day. If "somebody" is a person we can choose arbitrarily, the answer is $1$ since at least one person has been born on each day of the year, including 29 February.

In reality more people are born in the summer months, so the distribution of birthdays is variable and not at all uniform.

---

When considering 29 February as well as the usual 365 days in the first formulation of "somebody", the year also needs to be known in order to completely determine which day is "the day before my birthday". Once again, assume birthdays are uniformly distributed by day (not date). Since there are 97 leap years in the 400-year Gregorian cycle, the probability that a randomly chosen person has a specified birthday is $\frac{400}{400\cdot365+97}$ if that birthday is *not* 29 February and $\frac{97}{400\cdot365+97}$ otherwise.

Comment: It would be very interesting to see the solution *without* assuming a uniform distribution, including considering Feb 29.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor That'd just be making a distribution of all birthdays on the planet with 29 February taken into account - theoretically possible, since only a finite number of people have been born - and then, given your birthday, look at the day before it and look up the corresponding probability.

Comment: Wouldn't that just be 1/365.25 ?  I mean approximately, obviously the actual length of a year is slightly off and we cover it with the 100 yr. and 400 yr. rules for leap years.  Mind you, those exceptions being as far apart as they are, they're longer than the average human lifespan, so assuming two people who are both alive at the same time, 1/365.25 is probably good enough unless you're within one lifespan a century boundary that was not leap year.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman I said 365-day year.

Comment: How Feb 29 is treated should be specified. If my birthday is Mar 1, what counts as the day before? Feb 28, Feb 29 or both? I see compelling reasons for any solution. Obviously, the answer depends on that.

Comment: @nicola Added that in.

Comment: For anyone curious like I was, I found this link which analyzes the distribution of 480k birthdays over a 13 year period: https://www.panix.com/~murphy/bday.html. Conclusion: (as expected) the distribution is not uniform, with the peak appearing around Aug/Sep/Oct.

Comment: @fleablood Why must you write an entire paragraph just to tear down my opinion?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to make it hard:

There are $365$ choices her birthday (H) could be, and $365$ choices yours(Y) could be.  So there are are $365^2$ pairs of birthdays (H,Y).

Of those $365^2$ pairs there are $365$ cases where $Y = H+1$.  (Case 1: Y= Jan. 1-H=Dec 31.  Case 2: Y= Jan. 2-H= Jan 1. Case 3: Y=Jan. 3-H= Jan. 2..... Case 365: Y= Dec. 31, H= Dec. 30$.

So the probability is $\frac {365}{365^2} = \frac 1{365}$.

If you want to do it the easy way.

There are $365$ days she could be born.  The day before your birthday is precisely one of them and as likely as any other. So probability is $\frac 1{365}$.

.....

As for your birthday being Feb. 28....  No matter what your birthday is, the probability of her birthday being Feb. 27 is $\frac 1{365}$.

...

Finally your title is "What is the probability **somebody**'s birthday is the day before mine?"

The answer to *that* is 100%.  There are tens of millions of people with birthdays the day before you.

.....

" That seems too simple to me"  Why?  Why should it be complicated?

Comment: If you want to make it really hard (and not assume any knowledge about people's birthdays), the probability of somebody's birthday being the day before the asker's is not 100%. I asked [that very question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1071321/probability-that-n-people-collectively-occupy-all-365-birthdays) a few years ago, and the answer for 7 billion people would be extremely close to 100%, but not quite.

Comment: @maxb I thought about that but didn't want to confuse the issue.  It is, of course, $1 - (\frac {364.25}{365.25})^{7,000,000,000}$ which *looks* significantly less than $1$ than it actually is.  Thing is, for there *not* to be anybody having a birthday the day before there must be a date in which no-one on the planet was born and no one was born on that date in any year.  I think the statement "Every day millions of people are born" is a safe assumption in a "Junior Jumbo Book of Facts" way.

Comment: Once we get into real-world questions, probabilities become much more complicated. The fraction $\left(\frac{364.25}{365.25}\right)^{7\,000\,000\,000}$ is much smaller than any actual uncertainty you deserve to have about pretty much anything: there is an incredibly tiny but *much higher* probability that for some mysterious reason you're not aware of nobody is ever born on March 12th.

Comment: @fleablood ""Every day millions of people are born" isn't a safe assumption at all. For a population of 7bn, ignoring population growth, and assuming a global life expectancy of 50 years, there are only about 400,000 births per day. You would need make some creative assumptions to change that estimate to "millions" (plural).

Comment: ... or be off be a factor of 50.....

Answer (score 0):

Considering February 29 I say it is

1 in 365.25

as every four year we have an extra day.
The chance of another person being born on the day before is equally big as any other day of the year (except for February 29).